# Why ffdec_h264 not give debug information in gstreamer?

Tags: c, plugins, h.264, gstreamer

I'm working on multimedia application debugging on gstreamer and I'm using `GST_DEBUG` options to produce debug. For example the following command

```
GST_DEBUG=filesrc:5, qtdemux:5, ffdec_h264:5 gst-launch filesrc location=data/bdmp4/rihanna0.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demuxer demuxer. ! queue ! faad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demuxer. ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

will do the decoding of the input mp4 file while producing debug report about the gstreamer plugins `qtdemux`, `filesrc`, and `ffdec_h264`. The pipeline representation of the command is

[image]

My problem is that the above command shows debug information about `qtdemux` and `filesrc` plugins like you can see below

```
0:00:00.018162514 [334m12243[00m      0x219a4f0 [32;01mINFO   [00m [00m                 filesrc gstfilesrc.c:374:gst_file_src_set_location:[00m filename : data/bdmp4/rihanna0.mp4
0:00:00.018222356 [334m12243[00m      0x219a4f0 [32;01mINFO   [00m [00m               filesrc gstfilesrc.c:375:gst_file_src_set_location:[00m uri      :     file:///home/leonzo/Documents/workspace/videc/videcoframework/data/bdmp4/rihanna0.mp4
0:00:00.062045799 [334m12243[00m      0x219a4f0 [32;01mINFO   [00m [00m             filesrc gstfilesrc.c:969:gst_file_src_start:<filesrc0>[00m opening file data/bdmp4/rihanna0.mp4
0:00:00.062195045 [334m12243[00m      0x219a4f0 [32;01mINFO   [00m [00m             filesrc gstfilesrc.c:969:gst_file_src_start:<filesrc0>[00m opening file data/bdmp4/rihanna0.mp4
0:00:00.062564845 [334m12243[00m      0x2415c50 [37mLOG    [00m [00m             qtdemux qtdemux.c:3810:gst_qtdemux_loop:<demuxer>[00m loop at position 0, state 0
0:00:00.062671771 [334m12243[00m      0x2415c50 [37mLOG    [00m [00m             filesrc gstfilesrc.c:829:gst_file_src_create_read:<filesrc0>[00m Reading 16 bytes at offset 0x0
0:00:00.062717752 [334m12243[00m      0x2415c50 [36mDEBUG  [00m [00m             qtdemux qtdemux.c:1982:extract_initial_length_and_fourcc:[00m length 0x00000018
0:00:00.062746012 [334m12243[00m      0x2415c50 [36mDEBUG  [00m [00m             qtdemux qtdemux.c:1984:extract_initial_length_and_fourcc:[00m atom type ftyp
0:00:00.062782358 [334m12243[00m      0x2415c50 [37mLOG    [00m [00m             filesrc gstfilesrc.c:829:gst_file_src_create_read:<filesrc0>[00m Reading 24 bytes at offset 0x0
0:00:00.062808183 [334m12243[00m      0x2415c50 [36mDEBUG  [00m [00m             qtdemux qtdemux.c:1911:qtdemux_parse_ftyp:<demuxer>[00m major brand: mp42
0:00:00.062831369 [334m12243[00m      0x2415c50 [37mLOG    [00m [00m             qtdemux qtdemux.c:3810:gst_qtdemux_loop:<demuxer>[00m loop at position 24, state 0
0:00:00.062854234 [334m12243[00m      0x2415c50 [37mLOG    [00m [00m             filesrc gstfilesrc.c:829:gst_file_src_create_read:<filesrc0>[00m Reading 16 bytes at offset 0x18
0:00:00.062888181 [334m12243[00m      0x2415c50 [36mDEBUG  [00m [00m             qtdemux qtdemux.c:1982:extract_initial_length_and_fourcc:[00m length 0x024a4f05
0:00:00.062904672 [334m12243[00m      0x2415c50 [36mDEBUG  [00m [00m             qtdemux qtdemux.c:1984:extract_initial_length_and_fourcc:[00m atom type mdat
0:00:00.062922459 [334m12243[00m      0x2415c50 [37mLOG    [00m [00m             qtdemux 
....
```

But It doesn't give any debug report about the `ffdec_h264` plugin.

How to enable the debugging of the `ffdec_h264` pluging ? or Is there another h264 gstreamer decoding plugin which accept debugging

thansk you for any reply

Answer (score 0):

ffdec_h264 does not have its own debug category. The category for all gstffmpeg elements is ffmpeg, so you can do ffmpeg:5, or what I do *ff*:5